# Trying to install rails on xubuntu 14.04 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

gem install rails doesn't work for me. I did everything step by step from this site http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux (with latest versions of course), then I unistalled ruby, ruby gems, rvm and did everything from this site https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04 didn't work as well. I've seen many related topics and tried many solutions but nothing seems to work for me. I tried ruby-dev, ruby-all-dev, reinstalling ruby, I'm sure I have make installed, rvm requirements. I couldn't find anything that would solve the problem, so hopefully you guys will help me, please.

```
emil@emil-AO725:~$ gem install rails -v 4.2.4
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: minitest-5.8.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.8.0
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.4
Fetching: rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3
Fetching: mini_portile-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.6.2
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/emil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150905-28115-dnm7rt.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/emil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/home/emil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/emil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /home/emil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /home/emil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /home/emil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:337:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/emil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/emil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a ruby version manager, **try switching to ruby 2.2.2**. And try installing gems again. I had the same problem and i successfully installed my gems by switching to ruby 2.2.2. Maybe its a problem with ruby 2.2.3.

Comment: `Successfully installed rails-4.2.4` Thank you very much.

Just to clarify, if I installed rails using ruby 2.2.2 then I cannot use rails on ruby 2.2.3?

Comment: That depends on which version manager you use. RVM puts gems in "rubyversion/gemset/gems" folder, so each gem is specific to ruby version and gemset in the ruby version. Try the documentation and see if there is a "global" option when installing gems.